# About the references and values in OOP

Tags: java, reference

In this program, the variables "r" or "m" of circle_b points to the variables of the object circle_a OR they have a values (no point to another object) ??

```
class Circle
{
    public int r;
    public int m;

    public Circle(r, m)
    {
        this.r = r;
        this.m = m;
    }

    public getR() {return r;}
}


Main:
Circle circle_a = new Circle(10, 20);
Circle circle_b = new Circle(circle_a.getR(), circle_a.m);
```

**Edited:**

```
class MyClass {Integer var;}
MyClass a = new MyClass(); a.var = 5;
MyClass b = new MyClass(); b.var = a.var;
```

b.var points to a.var or has a selfvalue (b.var = 5)?

Comment: They're not pointers, so they don't point to anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variables are `int`, primitives, they're stored just as values, see [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: Yeah, but with Integer values, what will happen?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Can you explain what have you meant to say?

Comment: In the case of `Integer`, you'll just assign the new reference to `var`, the equivalent would be `a.var = Integer.valueOf(1);`, so `a.var` and `b.var` would be equal references, still that doesn't really matter, since you cannot change Integer (it's immutable).

Comment: Then que answer is "no, the value is independent, you can change the value of the variable a and b will not be modified.", Thank you very much.

Comment: @user3602030: Be very careful you really understand this. If you assign to `var` (`var = someOtherThing;`), yes, it's independent. But if you modify what `var` points to (you can't with `Integer`, but obviously with most classes you can, e.g. `var.modifyMe()`), that modifies what `var` points to, not `var`; that modification will, of course, be visible through any other variable pointing to the same object.

Answer (score 1):

Re your original question using `int`, they have the values, not references. Re your edit using `Integer`, it's the same answer (they have the values, not references) but the value in question is a reference to an object. (I'll cover that more in a moment.)

Whenever you see

```
a = b
```

...or

```
someMethod(a)
```

...you're seeing a *value* get copied.

With primitives like `int`, that's pretty much all we need to say. :-)

When the value in question refers to an object it's called an "object reference." It's still copied, but both copies continue to refer (point) to the same object.

ASCII-art is sometimes useful here...

### Primitives

This code:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 0;
```

Gives us:

```
+---+  +---+
| a |  | b |
+---+  +---+
| 5 |  | 0 |
+---+  +---+
```

If we do

```
b = a;
```

Then we have:

```
+---+  +---+
| a |  | b |
+---+  +---+
| 5 |  | 5 |
+---+  +---+
```

### Object References

This code:

```
Integer a = new Integer(5); // This is effectively what you did with your = 5;, the primitive gets promoted
Integer b = null;
```

Gives us:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+         +--------------------+
| (ref) |-------->|                    |
+-------+         | The Integer object |
                  | primitive value: 5 |
                  |                    |
                  +--------------------+

+-------+
|   b   |
+-------+
| null  |
+-------+
```

If we do

```
b = a;
```

Then we have:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+
| (ref) |---+     +--------------------+
+-------+   |     |                    |
            +---->| The Integer object |
                  | primitive value: 5 |
            +---->|                    |
+-------+   |     +--------------------+
|   b   |   |
+-------+   |
| (ref) |---/
+-------+
```

Now, with `Integer`, there's little opportunity for confusion because `Integer` instances are *immutable*: The have no state information that can be changed (an `Integer` instance whose primitive value is 42 will always have the primitive value 42). But most classes have *mutable* instances — that is, instances with state information that *can* be changed.

Let's consider `HashMap` instances, for example:

```
Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
Map<String, String> b = null;
```

Gives us:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+         +--------------------+
| (ref) |-------->|                    |
+-------+         | The HashMap object |
                  | size: 0            |
                  |                    |
                  +--------------------+

+-------+
|   b   |
+-------+
| null  |
+-------+
```

If we do

```
b = a;
```

Then we have:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+
| (ref) |---+     
+-------+   |     +--------------------+
            +---->|                    |
                  | The HashMap object |
            +---->| size: 0            |
+-------+   |     |                    |
|   b   |   |     +--------------------+
+-------+   |
| (ref) |---/
+-------+
```

All very well and good. Since `HashMap` instances are *mutable*, and both `a` and `b` refer to the same object, any changes we make to that object through the `a` reference are visible through the `b` reference, since they're pointing at the same object.

So if we do this:

```
a.put("foo", "bar");
```

we get:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+
| (ref) |---+     
+-------+   |     +--------------------+
            +---->|                    |
                  | The HashMap object |
            +---->| size: 1            |
+-------+   |     | "foo" = "bar"      |
|   b   |   |     |                    |
+-------+   |     +--------------------+
| (ref) |---/
+-------+
```

And so of course:

```
System.out.println(a.size()); // 1
System.out.println(b.size()); // 1
```

But the `a` and `b` *variables* remain completely independing. If you assign a *new* value to `b`:

```
b = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

You get:

```
+-------+
|   a   |
+-------+         +----------------------------+
| (ref) |-------->|                            |
+-------+         | The first HashMap object   |
                  | size: 1                    |
                  | "foo" = "bar"              |
                  |                            |
                  +----------------------------+

+-------+
|   b   |
+-------+         +----------------------------+
| (ref) |-------->|                            |
+-------+         | A different HashMap object |
                  | size: 0                    |
                  |                            |
                  +----------------------------+
```

Comment: Great explanation, but my question is more more particular. See my edited post, plase :). I'm not speaking of a class, I'm speaking of an attribute.

Comment: @user3602030: I don't see any unanswered part of your question, can be more specific? The above doesn't talk about classes (classes are irrelevant, this is true for static members, instance members, and local variables). The important thing is values, and whether the type of the container (member, variable) is primitive or an object type.